# APNS Houston gem moving to config files

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

I want to move the following lines to my `development.rb` and `production.rb` so I don't need to change the certificate path in both production and development (reducing merge conflicts). Right now they are defined in my controller, but moving them to my `config` folders does nothing. Am I doing this right ?

in my `development.rb`

```
APN = Houston::Client.development
APN.certificate = File.read("/path/to/apple_push_notification.pem")
```

And then in my controller

```
         notification = Houston::Notification.new(device: phone.device_token)
         notification.alert = "Push me!"
         notification.sound = "default"
         notification.badge = 1
         APN.push(notification)
```

https://github.com/nomad/Houston

Comment: I would love an answer to this.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to move those files in development and production

You can even do this by placing in your controller just by checking the environment

```
if Rails.env.development?
  APN = Houston::Client.development
  APN.certificate = File.read("/path/to/apple_push_notification.pem")
elsif Rails.env.production?
  APN = Houston::Client.production  ## ALL you have to change this to production
  APN.certificate = File.read("/path/to/apple_push_notification.pem")
end
```